# How can I find deleted or migrated questions?

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, migration

I voted to close a question (unable to find the link, something about accessing Oracle database tables from Python) that I initially thought was off-topic because there was no explicit GIS aspect mentioned in the question or the first answer.

However I subsequently added an answer listing several ArcGIS-specific methods to do the same thing.

Nevertheless the question seems to have disappeared without a trace, although I have read that 10k+ rep users can still see them. So:

1. What happened to that question?
2. Can I "un-vote" to close a question?
3. Should an on-topic answer to an off-topic question (at least at first glance) be considered before deleting/migrating/closing a question?

Comment: I cannot find any closed or deleted questions with the search terms "Oracle" and "Python".  Do you have any other clues about the nature of the missing question?

Comment: cx_Oracle was mentioned in one of the answers and pyodbc was mentioned in the question.

Comment: Found the link: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26885/python-script-access-data-from-databases ([Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=cx_oracle+site%3Agis.stackexchange.com) had apparently already crawled it)

Comment: blah238 have voted un-deleted the question - interesting question and is loosely a GIS Database question.

Comment: I voted to close it because (1) it is purely an Oracle/Python question and--this was the clincher--it's already cross-posted on SO. Let SO migrate it here if no satisfactory reply appears.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see the migrated question; do you have the link?

Answer (score 2):

Re 2: No, you cannot remove your close vote.  However, close votes "fade" after a few days if no action is taken.

Re 3: Yes, in rare cases some off-topic (or patently bad) questions can produce great replies and thereby deserve to stay.  (In this particular case, though, the cross-posting militated strongly against keeping the question here.)

Comment: The link above was actually broken when I used it earlier, but it works now. What happened?

Comment: I do not know.  As you well know, broken links can be due to many causes, some at the server and and some at your end.  I'll keep an eye on closed and deleted questions to see whether I can reproduce the behavior you report.